# compiler directive do not check for assembly version of same dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, compiler-construction

I have an ASP.net project (an Exact Synergy Enterprise custom project, which is ASP.net)

In this project, i reference a Exact.Data.dll of version 5.0.0.39. However, another referenced DLL refers also to Exact.Data.dll, but version 5.0.0.42. I know for a fact that these two are almost the same and i do not have the sources for the other DLL.

The project does not compile, because Visual Studio does not accept multiple versions of the same referenced DLL

Is there a way i can tell Visual Studio not to regard this as an error and just keep on compiling?

Answer (score 0):

If they are so similar that the other module should work with 5.0.0.39, equally your module should work with 5.0.0.42.

So you can have no objection to changing your reference to 5.0.0.42.